Failed to create partition during clean installation of Pop Os 22.04 LTS and other linux distributions
I have successfully installed Ubuntu Linux, but when I restarted, the Ubuntu Linux OS was lost and had to be reinstalled. Because when I restart it goes back to the boot menu. When I try to install other OS like Pop OS and Linux Mint, the installation fails while creating partitions. Is this error caused by SSD? However, when I checked the SSD, the SSD read gparted but couldn't create a partition and a message appeared (ped_partition_is_active (part)) in ../../libparted/disk.c:1418 in the ped_partition_is_flag_available() function failed. Now I use pop os try demo. Please help, and thank you.
$sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/loop0: 2.16 GiB, 2316550144 bytes, 4524512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 \* 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: BODI 512GB  
Units: sectors of 1 \* 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xacac7681
Disk /dev/sdb: 29.25 GiB, 31406948352 bytes, 61341696 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Blade  
Units: sectors of 1 \* 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x64324e52
Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  \*          0  5199935  5199936  2.5G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2           488     8679     8192    4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb3       5201920 61341695 56139776 26.8G 83 Linux
Disk /dev/zram0: 7.5 GiB, 8057257984 bytes, 1967104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 \* 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

$sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

NAME FSTYPE SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
loop0 squashfs 2.2G /rofs`your text`
sda 476.9G
└─sda1 1022M
sdb iso9660 29.3G Pop_OS 22.04 amd64 ├─sdb1 iso9660 2.5G /cdrom Pop_OS 22.04 amd64 ├─sdb2 vfat 4M
└─sdb3 ext4 26.8G /var/crash writable sdc 0B
zram0 7.5G \[SWAP\]


How do you know the installation was successful? Maybe there were some error messages that you missed?

Maybe I missed the error message because I was still learning to use Linux but I did a clean install until it finished and the restart button appeared

An installed Os is never just "lost" when rebooting. What happened when you rebooted your Ubuntu installation?

when I restart I can't go straight to the home page but go to the boot menu page and when I select Ubuntu it fails to reboot and goes back to the boot menu again

It looks like you have the very old MBR(msdos) partitioning with UEFI install. Linux seems to allow this, so it may work, but Windows has required gpt partitioning with UEFI since 2012. If new install, may be better to change now as conversion from MBR to gpt will totally erase all partitions on drive. Is system set for UEFI boot? What brand/model system. Have you tried Boot-Repair? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Post link from Summary Report it can make.
